# Are deforming force and stress always equal? If they are equal, then why does shape of the body get deformed?

Tags: solid-state-physics

If the deforming force is equal to the restoring force then there is no impact of the deforming force on the body. Then the shape of the body remains constant. How does the body deform, then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the restoring force will be equal to the deforming force *once equilibrium is reached*.  But before that, the deforming force will be greater than the restoring force, and deformation will occur then.  Once equilibrium is reached, no more deformation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little problematic - force and stress are distinct physical quantities, so they can't possibly be equal. Secondly the 'shape' of a body can remain constant even while it is deforming (through a volume change) - as in the case of hydrostatic compression for instance.

Shape can be changed without changing volume- this is a special case of deformation.

Volume can be changed without changing shape - this is a special case of deformation.

The general case lies between both these extremes.

In all three situations, the restoring force acts AFTER the force causing deformation is removed. The restoring force comes from elasticity, and the deformation is elastic. Beyond a certain limit, elasticity breaks down, linear harmonic approximations break down and the restoring force is no longer equal to the deformation force.